# How does $ a\sin(a-b) $ become $2a\sin\frac{a-b}{2}\cos\frac{a-b}{2}$?

Tags: trigonometry

I am doing *Elements of Geometry* by S.L. Loney. In one exercice, the answer requires to simplify a trigonometric equation from
$$ a\sin(a-b) $$ to $$2a\sin\frac{a-b}{2}\cos\frac{a-b}{2}$$
How can you go from one form to the other?

I found a video online that do the exact same problem from the book but do not explain how the transformation is done. For reference: https://youtu.be/SmvA3wOXEhA?t=301

How can you go from the first form to the last form? I'm looking through my trigonometric book and can't find this trig identity.

Comment: Use the double angle identity $\sin(2x) = 2\sin x \cos x$ with $x = \frac{a - b}{2}$.

Comment: See [trigonometric identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Angle_sum_and_difference_identities), from which you can derive $\sin(2\theta) = 2\sin(\theta)\cos(\theta)$.

Comment: oh I see now. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Use the [double angle formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Multiple-angle_formulae) for $\sin$, which states that $\sin(2x)=2\sin(x)\cos(x)$ for all values of $x$. By setting $x=(a-b)/2$, we see that
$$
\sin(a-b)=\sin\left(2\times\frac{a-b}{2}\right)=2\sin\left(\frac{a-b}{2}\right)\cos\left(\frac{a-b}{2}\right) \, .
$$
If we multiply both sides of this equation by $a$, we obtain the desired result.

Comment: I did not know this trick existed, very clever. Thank you!

Comment: No problem, @Sciencelearner! Let me know if you have any questions.